# Is my Manifest is lacking anything for the Windows Market publishing

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, publishing

Is my Manifest is lacking anything for the Windows Market publishing?

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
      <App xmlns="" ProductID="{fdfc7d73-10e1-49ce-8961-81728d0983b2}" Title="Car News RSS" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal"  Author="Robert Kilar" Description="RSS Client which provides latest news from the motorworld." Publisher="Robert Kilar">
        <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
        <Capabilities>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
          <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
        </Capabilities>
        <Tasks>
          <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
        </Tasks>
        <Tokens>
          <PrimaryToken TokenID="RSSToken" TaskName="_default">
            <TemplateType5>
              <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
              <Count>0</Count>
              <Title>RSS car</Title>
            </TemplateType5>
          </PrimaryToken>
        </Tokens>
      </App>
    </Deployment>
```

Comment: did you get an error when trying to use it or do you just need proofread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i am sure that you do not want to fish FOR you, but would rather learn how to handle your own rod & reel:

microsoft publishes [these recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for publishing app for windows market

[this guide](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/5-tips-for-a-successful-wp7-marketplace-submission) may be slightly outdated, but has general information that can be quite handy.

and, finally, [this guide](http://solutions.developer.com/ms/mobile/submissions-and-marketplace/the-windows-8-store-certification-process-for-windows-phone-developers.html) to publishing apps in windows market has some quite sound advice.